# Reduce to Sturm-liouville $My=x^2y''+3xy+y$

Tags: sturm-liouville

I need to reduce to sturm-liouville using the 'integrating factor' method:

$$My=x^2y''+3xy+y$$ where y=y(x). I am looking at my notes and I know the Sturm-Liouville form is $$\left(P(x)y'\right)'+Q(x)y$$ However, I don't understand what to do. If someone can help me in DETAIL that will be much appreciated.

Thanks!!

I have a sense at what to do but my professor notes are a little hard to understand.

Comment: What is $M$ in $\quad My=x^2y''+3xy+y$ ?

Comment: @JJacquelin In the notes it says consider a sec. order lin. homo. diff. operator $My=y''+b(x)y'+c(x)y$

Comment: Do you mean M(y)= y''+ 3xy'+ y?

Comment: @user247327 no it says $x^2y''$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry- my question was really about the "3xy" term and I mistyped.  Do you mean $M(y)= x^2y''+ 3xy'+ y$?  If so then let p(x) be the factor you want: we want $x^2p(x)y''+ 3xp(x)y'= (x^2p(x)y')'$.  By the product rule that right side is $x^2p(x)y''+ 2xp(x)y'+ x^2p'(x)y'= x^2p(x)y''+ (2xp(x)+ x^2p'(x))y'$ which must equal $x^2p(x)y''+ 3xp(x)y'$.  That is, we must have $2xp(x)+ x^2p'(x)= 3xp(x)$ which gives $p'(x)= p(x)/x$ so $dp/p= dx/x$.  Integrating both sides, $ln(p)= ln(x)+ C$ and, taking the exponential, $p(x)= C'x$ where $C'= e^C$.  Since we only need a single function, take C'= 1.  The integrating factor is x:
$xM(y)= x^3y''+ 3x^2y'+ xy= (x^3y')'+ xy$.